# Center floated right element when second is floated right

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, center

I'm adding fixed bar on the bottom of page, first I have 100% width fixed container, which contains 2 elements. First one is the content and second one closes the bar.

I want first element, i.e. "mixtext" to be centered in the bar, and second element, close button to be always on right, and I want them to be on the same line. Can you suggest how can I do that?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="mixwrap">
  <span id="mixtext">
    [Text that needs to be centered within the space from left to the next element]
  </span>
  <span id="mixclose">
    <input type="button" id="mixclosebut" onclick="document.getElementById('mixwrap').style.display = 'none';">
  </span>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#mixwrap {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #555;
  color: white;
}

#mixtext {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: MetaBold, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

#mixclose {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
```

Also, I want to remember user's choice, when someone clicks close button, js just sets display:none for element, but when user navigates to other page, div is showing again. How can I hide it so user won't see it after navigating to other page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the position of `#mixclose` and `#mixtext`, and change them to divs:

```
<div id="mixwrap">
  <div id="mixclose"><input type="button" id="mixclosebut"
       value="Test" onclick="document.getElementById('mixwrap').style.display = 'none';">
  </div>

  <div id="mixtext">
    [Text that needs to be centered within the space from left to the next element]
  </div>
</div>
```

and remove the `float: left` from the `#mixtext` css:

```
#mixtext {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: MetaBold, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
```

Now `#mixtext` will expand to 100% of it's available space, and `#mixclose` will float to the right.

**Edit:**

In regards to your last question, to remember the users setting to display `#mixtext` or not, you would have to either use cookies or a server side language.

Answer (score 0):

`#mixtext` - SPANs expand to the size of their CONTENTS, so `text-align:center` is meaningless. There is no white-space in the element, so the text will always be "centered" in its wrapper.

`#mixtext` need to be a DIV in order to contain white-space.

DIVs expand to take up the width of their CONTAINER, so it will become 100% wide unless told otherwise. You need to give #mixtext a WIDTH to give your button some space.

Because you have `float:left` on #mixtext, the container of the text will always be on the left of the screen, not centered.

To center the DIV, since there is no such thing as `float:center`, we need to use margins to center it. This uses the "[negative margin centering trick](http://www.chazzuka.com/centering-layout-using-css-positioning-negative-margin-100/)"

Here's what we end up with: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/74m9C/1/

```
#mixtext {
text-align: center;
padding: 8px;
font-family: MetaBold, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
width:600px;
position:relative;    
float:left;    
left:50%;  
margin-left:-300px;
border:1px solid #ff0000;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
#mixwrap {
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background: #555;
color: white;
}

#mixtext {
width:200px;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 8px;
font-family: MetaBold, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#mixclose {
width:30px;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
}

</style>
<div id="mixwrap">
<div id="mixtext">
[Text that needs to be centered within the space from left to the next element]
</div>
<div id="mixclose"><input type="button" id="mixclosebut" onclick="document.getElementById('mixwrap').style.display = 'none';">
</div>
</div>
```

As for removing the element and keeping it removed, you need code that will examine postback and then check for the element to see if its there.